# Why is my nested dictionary repeating a key?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am building a nested dictionary with several elements that im scraping from https://www.koodomobile.com/rate-plans?INTCMP=KMNew_NavMenu_Shop_Plans. However, even though I can actively see that im scraping accurate data(when I print), it seems to repeat the values of a key thoughtout the whole dict. Some of the things repeated are monthly cost, dataNum, minutes, Messages.

I would like to be able to correctly nest my dictionary planPermutation inside of another dictionary planDicts.

heres an example of my output:

> {
>   'Bring your own device 30': {'plan type Name': 'Bring your own device', 'monthlyCost': 75, 'dataNum': 10000, 'minutes': 'Unlimited', 'messaging': 'Unlimited'},
>
> 'Bring your own device 35': {'plan type Name': 'Bring your own device', 'monthlyCost': 75, 'dataNum': 10000, 'minutes': 'Unlimited', 'messaging': 'Unlimited'},
>
> 'Bring your own device 45': {'plan type Name': 'Bring your own device', 'monthlyCost': 75, 'dataNum': 10000, 'minutes': 'Unlimited', 'messaging': 'Unlimited'}, 
>   ...
>   }

```
def planDictsGenerator():
                planPermutation = {}
                index = 1

                # name
                planName = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#block-system-main > div > div > div.view-content > div.rate-plan-block > div.tab-header-wrapper > h2')))
                planName = str(planName[0].text)
                planPermutation["plan type Name"] = planName

                subplans = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.panel-col-first')))
                for plan in subplans:
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", plan)
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", plan)
                    time.sleep(1)

                    # monthlyCost
                    monthlyCost = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.active .koodo-currency')))
                    monthlyCost = monthlyCost[0].text
                    monthlyCost = int(monthlyCost.replace('$', ''))
                    planPermutation["monthlyCost"] = monthlyCost

                    # Data
                    dataNum = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.active .views-field-field-data-mobile-value strong')))
                    dataNum = dataNum[0].text
                    if "GB" in dataNum:
                        dataNum = int(dataNum.replace(' GB', '')) * 1000
                    else:
                        dataNum = int(dataNum.replace(' MB', ''))
                    planPermutation["dataNum"] = dataNum

                    # minutes
                    minutes = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.active .views-field-field-canada-wide-any-min-mobile strong')))
                    minutes = minutes[0].text
                    if "Unlimited" in minutes:
                        minutes = "Unlimited"
                    else:
                        minutes = int(minutes)

                    planPermutation["minutes"] = minutes

                    # messaging
                    messaging = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.active .views-field-field-unlim-text-and-pic-mobile strong')))
                    messaging = messaging[0].text
                    if "Unlimited" in messaging:
                        messaging = "Unlimited"
                    else:
                        messaging = int(messaging)

                    planPermutation["messaging"] = messaging

                    dictName = planName + " " + str(monthlyCost)
                    planDicts[dictName] = planPermutation
                    print(planPermutation)


  [1]: https://www.koodomobile.com/rate-plans?INTCMP=KMNew_NavMenu_Shop_Plans
```

Comment: The key is not repeating in one dictionary, it's repeating across several dictionaries. Note that these whole dictionaries are just the values of the top level dictionary.

Comment: The lower level dictionary is the one thats presenting an issue regarding accurate information. Im not sure whats causing it to repeat those values through out the whole dictionary.

Comment: I can't clearly understand what format of dict you want. Can you provide a example ?